# CI - Sanitizing the form inputs from quotes

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, sanitization, codeigniter-form-helper

I was facing an issue where if I submit characters like single quotes ( ' ) or double quotes ( " ) and if I retain the values after submitting the form, (due to validation failure, for instance), I was getting form values like ' and "

I tried a lot of things like -

- accessing form values by `$this->input->post("field", true)` instead of `$_POST`,
- enabling XSS filtering from config,
- using `$this->security->xss_clean($data);`

But nothing helped.
Finally, I went to system\helpers\form_helper.php and changed function form_input at line 177 as follows -

**Previous** : `$defaults = array('type' => 'text', 'name' => (( ! is_array($data)) ? $data : ''), 'value' => $value);`

**After** : `$defaults = array('type' => 'text', 'name' => (( ! is_array($data)) ? $data : ''), 'value' => html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'));`

This has solved my problem without any break so far.

All I want to know if this is the correct way to serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not super sure about the issue you were having but editing the system file to fix it is not a great idea. You should *never* change anything in the system folder, the proper way to make your change would be to extend the form helper by creating the file `application/helpers/MY_form_helper.php` (using your own prefix, defined in `application/config/config.php`) and inside the file override the function you want to change. It should look something like this...

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

if ( ! function_exists('form_input'))
{
    /**
    * Text Input Field
    *
    * @param    mixed
    * @param    string
    * @param    string
    * @return   string
    */
    function form_input($data = '', $value = '', $extra = '')
    {
        $defaults = array(
            'type' => 'text',
            'name' => is_array($data) ? '' : $data,
            'value' => html_entity_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
        );
        return '<input '._parse_form_attributes($data, $defaults).$extra." />\n";
    }
}

/* End of file MY_form_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/MY_form_helper.php */
```